# bash current working directory with '~' replacing path to home folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to echo current directory with `~` replacing home directory?

Example:
`~/inbox` instead of `/home/john/inbox`

*Home directory should not be hardcoded.*
*There are `$PWD` and `$HOME` variables.*
*A built-in bash tool would be nice.*

Answer (score 7):

```
echo "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
```

This substitutes `$HOME` with `~`. The `#` is like `^` in a regex: it anchors the match to the beginning of the string. The `\~` replaces `$HOME` with a literal tilde; if we didn't use the `\` escape, the `~` would re-expand to `$HOME` and effectively do nothing.

Comment: Fails for HOME="/home/bobby" and PWD="/home/bobbytables".

Answer (score 5):

This should work under any POSIX shell:

```
pwd | sed "s|^$HOME|~|"
```